# How to replace values in numpy ndarray with values from a separate list

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to create a simulation where I have an numpy ndarry and want to replace the elements within the array with a numeric value that's generated in a separate list, which has all the random outcomes from each iteration of the simulation.

I'm very new to using arrays so I'm just beginning to learn about them. I'm not sure what the most time-efficient way is (perhaps vectorization is the best route to take here?) I know how to do this through the combined use of lists, list comprehension, and for loops but my current methods are very, very slow for the scale I want to be able to do this at. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve at a much smaller scale

```
import numpy as np

simulations = 10
names = [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'], ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']]
arr = np.asarray([names] * simulations)

name_value = []
for name_list in names:
    for i in name_list:
        if i not in name_value:
            name_value.append({'name': i, 'value': random.sample(range(0, 1000), simulations)})
```

Where arr looks like so:

```
array([[['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']],

       [['Joe', 'Mary', 'Tim'],
        ['Jake', 'Bob', 'Jane']]], dtype='<U4')
```

and name_value is

```
[{'name': 'Joe', 'value': [101, 732, 74, 288, 410, 401, 229, 912, 757, 472]},
 {'name': 'Mary', 'value': [512, 220, 943, 840, 128, 582, 264, 530, 655, 619]},
 {'name': 'Tim', 'value': [510, 131, 336, 709, 379, 102, 238, 672, 767, 561]},
 {'name': 'Jake', 'value': [853, 748, 443, 104, 327, 132, 636, 347, 810, 749]},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'value': [290, 950, 448, 285, 577, 219, 656, 852, 626, 872]},
 {'name': 'Jane', 'value': [202, 523, 902, 772, 48, 821, 910, 397, 915, 95]}]
```

and my desired output looks like this

```
array([[[101, 512, 510],
        [853, 290, 202]],

       [[732, 220, 131],
        [748, 950, 523]],

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`name_value` is a list of `dict`, `i` is a `str` from `name_list` from `names`. This search is already not efficient and `i not in name_value` should always be `True`. Since you are populating `name_value` you don't either need to check.

By the way, you can just produce the random samples you need and then reshape the result:

```
import random
import numpy as np
simulations = 10

_vaules = random.sample(range(0, 1000), simulations*3*2)
output = np.reshape(_vaules, (simulations, 2, 3))
print(output)
```

or even better:

```
output = np.random.randint(1000, size=simulations*2*3).reshape((simulations,2,3))
```

then iterating over the first index of the `output` array you have the smaller array for your agents like:

```
  print(output[0,:,:])
  #array([[427,  58, 796],
  #      [764, 775, 297]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand now that the way I created name_values is inefficient, but I was just coding up some dummy data to better illustrate my problem. Your solution is certainly fast but it doesn't have an array populated with names and then replaces those names with the numeric value tied to the simulation sequence.

Comment: In arrays, the type is defined (int, float, 32/64 bits int, object, etc). To populate it with strings and then replace them with numbers (your results are numbers, right?) requires the type to be 'object' and you lose many of the advantages of using an array.
Maybe instead of replacing you may use an array with the same shape and the appropriate type.
You could even use an array whose elements are arrays and the inner arrays have the fields defined with the names (if the names don't change) like a supercharged list of dicts  (not as flexible but faster).